# Delete Hyper-V Checkpoints in Windows 10

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 Build 10586 desktop computer with Client Hyper-V installed. I have a couple VMs that I created checkpoints on, however I don't want those checkpoints anymore. How do I delete the checkpoint, but maintain the current state of the VM?

Answer (score 1):

`Get-VMCheckpoint -VMName vm_name_here | Remove-VMCheckpoint`
Will do the trick. Tested on my

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-host

Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.0.10586.122
```